# Monochromatic color palette generation with d3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

Is there a built in method to generate monochromatic colors with d3 library when given a color input?

I have search around but I find nothing.

The closest way I figure out now is:

1. Convert the provided color into HSL format
2. Pick up the saturation and save it as `s1`
3. Find the minimum saturation by using `s1-1` and save it as `s2`
4. Interpolate `s1` and `s2` by 10 with d3
5. Use the absolute value of the interpolated saturation to generate color palette by fixing (**H**)ue and (**L**)ight

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. One of them is using a [sequential scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleSequential).

For instance, given your provided colour (say, blue) in HSL format...

```
const color = d3.hsl("blue");
```

...all you need is:

```
const scale = d3.scaleSequential(t => d3.hsl(color.h, color.s * t, color.l) + "");
```

The value you'll pass to the interpolator goes from 0 to 1. As you can see, we'll multiply the saturation value by that number (`color.s * t`), so it will effectively go from 0 to its normal value.

Here is a demo creating a palette with 40 values:

```js
const color = d3.hsl("blue");
const scale = d3.scaleSequential(t => d3.hsl(color.h, color.s * t, color.l) + "").domain([0, 40]);
d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(40))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have updated and added **absolute value** in my question to handle colors having low *saturation*. Can you update your answer accordingly so i can accept your answer?

Comment: I'm already doing what you asked, H and L are fixed.

Comment: My **absolute** value is implying that I wish to interpolate data, assuming the **Saturation**  is 0.4, between [0 to 0.4] and [0.4 to 1], and not just [0 to 0.4] alone like what you did in your solution. But I think you are fairly close to what i want.